# How to display contents from database using json and webapi

Tags: c#

I'm new to webapi. I'm fetching the data from db using data table in webapi. I want to pass this data as json array.

How can I do this? Any help is appreciable

```
public class theatresController: ApiController {

    [HttpGet]
    public static DataTable GetAlltheatredet() {
        try {
            string connString = "Server=localhost;database=mytable;uid=root;";
            string query = "SELECT TheatName FROM `mytable`.`theatredetails`";
            MySqlDataAdapter ma = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connString);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            ma.Fill(DS);
            return DS.Tables[0];
        } catch (MySqlException e) {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

What do next?

Comment: the `json` will be passed to client by default.What client are you using?`Javascript` ? `.Net`?You'll need to make a `HTTP` request to fetch it at your client.For `javascript` or `JQuery` make an `ajax` `GET` request.For `.Net` client use `HttpWebRequest` object.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two simple way one is using StringBuilder class and another is by using Json.NET assembly 
Reference: 
[Converting datatable to JsonObject](http://jqueryasp.net/convert-datatable-to-json-object-in-asp-net-csharp/)

Using Newtonsoft.json:

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DbEmployee;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_EmpDetails", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    string JSONresult;
    JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);  
    Response.Write(JSONresult);
```

Comment: serializing a `DataTable` comes with a few unnecessary properties unless otherwise handled.